# Blackberry 10 Simulator, is it possible to disable 3D Acceleration?

Tags: blackberry-10

I can't seem to start the Blackberry 10 simulator from VMWare Player, it gets to the point where it says `START SERVICE: screen` but doesn't do anything beyond that.

I was reading about this and apprently it's because VMWare doesn't detect 3D Acceleration capabilities on my graphics card. I'm pretty sure my graphics card does NOT support 3D Acceleration because this is my work machine and upper management probably didn't anticipate my need for such.

In VMWare Player, when I go to `Player/Manage/Virtual Machine Settings/` and then on to the Display tab, there is a checkbox next to `Accelerate 3D graphics` and it is checked, but I cannot uncheck it as it is grayed out. In fact everything under the Display tab is grayed out.

How can I disable 3D Acceleration? And would doing this allow me to use the simulator??

Comment: A quick google search shows [this blog entry](http://www.wisdomitsol.com/Blog/blackberry/android-to-blackberry-10/blackberry-10-simulator-stuck-at-Starting-screen) explaining how to select safe mode at boot.

Comment: Thanks! I've followed the steps and have gotten one step further. I'm not sure how long it's supposed to take to load, but right now it's stuck on the loading screen.

Comment: Not working. It it never gets past the loading screen

Comment: It takes some time to load (and a lot more if your CPU is not virtualization-enabled)

Comment: What spec is your machine? The Simulator is RAM hungry and very slow on low spec machines. I would strongly advise you enable hardware hardware virtualisation in your BIOS otherwise you'll be in for a very long wait whilst it boots (if it boots at all).

Answer (score 0):

Just after your system starts it will get you briefly through a resolution list, unless you change it manually the system will continue booting 5 seconds later picking by default the first mode from the list,

to bypass this kind of error i chose one of the safe suggested modes on the bottom of the list, for example: in the following screenshot it will be 4,5 or 6

PS : don't forget to click somewhere inside the VMWarePlayer window to interact with the loaded system before typing the choice number with you keyboard then type enter (before the 5 seconds elapses)

[image: BB Simulator Loading]